# Does using BigDecimal over double for basic integer divisions do anything if you're rounding to 1 decimal place?

Tags: java, formatting, numbers, currency, bigdecimal

I'm dealing with money, and I have a method that deals with a simple integer division. Since I have to return the value as double anyway, is cluttering my code with BigDecimal effective here?

Is it considered the more 'correct' option for a case like this?

Comment: If you have to return the value as a `double`, you're already pretty much out of luck for getting the correct answer.  But the answer is, "it depends how big the values are to the left of the decimal."

Comment: Can you include the relevant code in the question? What is a "simple integer division"? Is the dividend guaranteed to be an integer multiple of the divisor?

Comment: *I have to return the value as double anyway*. Really?

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

Always use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for money.

You said:

> I have to return the value as double

**Never return a `double` for money.** Floating-point types trade away accuracy for speed of execution. Bookkeepers & accountants prefer accuracy over speed.

For presentation, return text, a formatted `String`.

You said:

> simple integer division

If you want a fractional result, and you want accuracy, always use `BigDecimal` and its `divide` methods.

If you want only whole numbers, use integer types (`int`, `long`, `Integer`, `Long`, or `BigInteger`) but not `double`.

## Never use `double` with money

You said:

> Since I have to return the value as double anyway

Never use `double` [when accuracy matters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems). Usually that includes money.

So if you are returning `double`, the rest of **your question is moot**. You’ve already thrown accurate results out the window.

Here is an example using only one decimal place.

```
double x = 0.1 * 0.1 * 10 ;
System.out.println( x ) ;
```

> 0.10000000000000002

Compare that behavior to [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

```
BigDecimal y = new BigDecimal( "0.1" ).multiply( new BigDecimal ( "0.1" ) ).multiply( new BigDecimal ( "10" ) ) ;
System.out.println( y ) ;
```

> 0.10

See this [run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/UeSfev).

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you are only dealing with 1 decimal place, it's more effective to use double, because BigDecimal is used for high precision calculations with a lot more decimals.

To properly use double, I suggest you to use DecimalFormat to round the values if you need it, for example:

```
double a = 10;
double b = 3;
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat(".00");
format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.UP);

System.out.println(format.format(a / b));
```

The output of this code will be 3.34, because DecimalFormat are formatting to 2 decimals and rounding mode are rounding up, I leave here a couple of links with all the information you need to properly use decimal format and rounding mode to your calculations:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html

Comment: You are rounding the string representation of the result, not the actual result.

Comment: *...because BigDecimal is used for high precision calculations...* It can be, but mostly it's used for monetary arithmetic.